# SQL: Add relations to local temp Declared tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

Here is the full query

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE(
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Salary INT NOT NULL,
  [Middle Name] VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @Books TABLE(
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Books_Customer
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) 
    REFERENCES Customers(Id)
);
```

I get an error when trying to run this query

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.
```

So, Is it possible to add relations into local declared table variables and how if not like this?

Comment: You can't have foreign keys in table variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't create foreign key with the reference of variable or temp table. It is because temp/variable are dropped when you finish your operation. In exceptional cases when you kill your spid then it may permitted to add foreign key in temp table. In that case dropping of temp or variable table required in specific order that may be an issue.